# Redirect to where user was before authentication - but with registration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I can see in the `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware:

```
return $next($request);
```

Which lets a user return to where they were once they log in.

Is there a way to achieve similar if the user reaches the auth middleware, is asked to login, but instead registers, once registered how can the user go back to the original page automatically?

Comment: If I understand your question. By default Laravel work as you want.

Comment: No, after register it hits the url defined in $redirectTo in the RegisterController.php file

Comment: after successfully register   return redirect('/');

Answer (score 2):

You could add the following lines functions to the `RegistrationController.php`

```php
public function showRegistrationForm ()
{
    session(['before_registration_url' => url()->previous()]);

    return view('auth.register');
}

protected function redirectTo ()
{
    $url = session('before_registration_url');
    session()->forget('before_registration_url');

    return $url;
}
```

The `showRegistrationForm` function will overwrite the default function in the `RegistersUsers` trait. It will store the previous url in the current session and then return the default view.

the `redirectTo` function will after you have been registered retrieve the stored url, remove the url from the session and then return the url.

Or if you want to store the url that the user was on before he was being redirected to the login form you can add this to the `LoginController`:

```php
public function showLoginForm()
{
    session(['before_registration_url' => url()->previous()]);

    return view('auth.login');
}
```

It depends on where the registration form is placed.

**--added--**

you also could use the `url.intended` because this is being set when the middleware redirects you to the login:

```php
protected function redirectTo ()
{
    return session('url.intended');
}
```